# Router outlet inside a module not working with ngForm

Tags: angular, router-outlet

I have a module which is loaded at /dashboard in my main app module, this module has its own router outlet with 3 child routes as it follows:

dashboard-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, /*canActivate: [AuthGuard], canActivateChild: [ AuthGuard ],*/ children: [
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'usuarios', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'proyectos', component: AdminProyectosComponent},
    {path: 'productos', component: AdminProductosComponent},
    {path: 'usuarios', component: AdminUsuariosComponent},
  ] }
];
```

this works well and  the result is like this: [image: dashboard]

but when I add this line to my form in my component dasboardmodule>admin-usuarios>admin-usuarios.component.html

```
#usuarioForm="ngForm"
```

everything breaks, there is this error in the console:

```
error NG8003: No directive found with exportAs 'ngForm'.

13       <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmitNuevoUsuario(usuarioForm)"  #usuarioForm="ngForm">
```

and when i try to navigate to any other route in my app there is this error in the chrome console (I think this is caused by the compilation, any of my 2 router outlet works):

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot activate an already activated outlet
Error: Cannot activate an already activated outlet
```

I really dont know why this happens.

Things I tried:

- Used a named outlet and In the navigation: [routerLink]="['users', {outlets: {admin: 'users'}}]
- Getting my component out of the module folder and only call it
- Importing FormsModule in my dashboard.module.ts and in my app.module.ts

Comment: can you please provide stackblitz url ?

Comment: did you added `FormsModule` in your root module or dashboard module ?

Comment: Piyush jain Both of them

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide stackblitz url ?